# Execute post-integration-test phase when pre-integration-tests fail

Tags: maven, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin

During `pre-integration-tests` Maven phase I'm setting up some tests environment.

Let's suppose I'm starting a database and a mock server (in that order)

Sometimes, the port of the mock server is already allocated, so my build fails in `pre-integration-tests` phase.

The problem? The database was started and was not shut down in `post-integration-tests` because that phase was not executed at all.

Maven always executes `post-integration-tests` even if there were errors in `integration-tests`, which is great, but I need to also execute `post-integration-tests` when `pre-integration-tests` phase has failed.

Any advice?

Thanks!